Door lock detection system
We have some doors that already have basic open/closed electic loop built in (micro switch based, unknown system, something like older version of https://www.adiglobaldistribution.us/Catalog/shop-brands/camden-door-controls/CM-CXED179DL), but the wires are not connected to anything at the moment. I would like to install a unit that detects if each door is locked and sends the information wirelessly to a central unit that can show something like door 1 = locked, door 2 = locked etc. on a screen or through LEDs. All system parts can have access to voltage, but batteries are also fine.
Are there off-the-shelf systmes that can fit this description? Or do I need to invent it myself using Arduinos?
I specifically need a central display unit and therefore apps do not cut it, I also need to use the existing lock sensors, simply checking that the door is closed in not enough.

yes, there are off the shelf systems that you could use

Could you please recommend something as an example?

A COTS solution is just an internet search away. If you need a starting point, the Chinese company Sonoff makes plenty of hacker friendly components that can be bought, re-programmed from github.com projects and assembled into a system that may or may not meet your needs. For instance, I've see COTS devices that can tell if a door is closed. But not if a door is locked.

shopping questions are off topic here ...  try asking at https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions
